# Is there a way to make my HTTP rules work for iOS simulator with Requestly?

Tags: networking, ios, requestly

I'm using requestly to replace certain network calls with local calls, so I can develop and debug my JS code on a live website.

I'm trying to do the same now through iOS simulator, but found no way to apply the rules to the Simulator.

Is there an option I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

Requestly desktop and other similar tools run a proxy server on your local machine. You can get the proxy URL from Requestly and set it wherever required.

To use a proxy in iOS simulator you need to first set it to the system (choose Everywhere System Wide in Requestly) and then in your xcode project's scheme, define two variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` with value of the proxy URL and voilà.

To intercept HTTPS traffic you also need to install a root certificate.

In your simulator, launch Safari and navigate to http://requestly.io/ssl (Use http here, not https), tap **Allow** to download the Requestly Root Certificate and install it. Next, navigate to **Settings > About > Certificate Trust Settings** and enable RQProxy CA to mark it as trusted.

Edit: Their docs now has a [detailed guide](https://docs.requestly.io/guides/debugging-https-traffic-in-ios-simulator) explaining step-by-step how to setup Requestly with iOS simulator